# How to draw a line tied to a moving circle with Konva.JS?

Tags: konvajs

I have a problem: I need to constantly reconnect the ends of the line connecting the next four circles in Konva.JS. How can I do it? Faced with such a problem?

Comment: please share sample code of what you have tried.

Comment: Please provide a sketch or image of what you are trying to do.